# Gibberish arabic/persian comments in android studio 2.2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

After installing the new update of android studio 2.2.3, the comments I made in Persian language are turned into gibberish. If I copy them and paste anywhere outside android studio, they will be turned back to their normal form.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String string = "من اندروید ستودیو 2.2.3 استفاده میکنم";
        //من اندروید ستودیو 2.2.3 استفاده میکنم
        /*من اندروید ستودیو 2.2.3 استفاده میکنم*/
    }
}
```

[image]

As you see in the image: if I store them as a string variable the text characters are shown correctly but if I comment the same text its characters will turn completely gibberish and obscure.

Can anybody help me resolve this issue? or is this some sort of bug?
Thanks.

Comment: Which file encoding do you use in Android Studio?

Comment: how can I know that?

Comment: I found it. On the Android Studio status bar its written UTF-8.

Comment: Can you paste your code as well? So then others could try to reproduce this error. It indeed seems strange.

Comment: My problem is not with my code. The problem is with the Android Studio 2.2.3 itself. When I try to comment in Persian language it turns into ambiguous set of characters. The code does not matter here. the problem is with commenting.

Comment: Above picture shows a sample scenario and it is the same in all my projects. This problem was not there before Android Studio 2.2.3.

Comment: My comment seems to have been ambigous: Could you please copy&paste everything from the picture to here? This way someone can test the error himself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I will share the code as well.

Comment: try changing font for comments?

Comment: I went to Settings>Editor>Colors & Fonts>Font, but everything below Editor Font is grayed out and I am not able to change anything. Primary font is Monospaced and "Show only monospaced fonts" checkbox is ticked.

Comment: I succeeded changing the font. Unfortunately it didn't help either.

Comment: I've pasted your text into my Android Studio 2.2.3 and it worked fine. When I go to Settings>Editor>Colors & Fonts>Font my "Show only monospaced fonts"-box is not ticked. Do you maybe have a custom scheme activated there? Look for "Scheme>Default". Else I would guess, that AS uses a different font for comments, which does not support Persian? So maybe AS is missing a certain font? Might help if you ask your question somewhere here: https://developer.android.com/support.html ... the AS developers might read this.

Comment: I am also having "Scheme>Default". I have posted this as an Android Studio bug using the link you have provided: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231143. Thanks for being very helpful.